# Repeated alert: "MAMP PRO.app" would like to access data from other apps

Tags: permission, mamp

I recently migrated to a new Macbook Pro. Now every time I re-open Mamp I get the alert `"MAMP PRO.app" would like to access data from other apps`. Even if I choose to "Allow" it will pop up again if I close the app and open it. What is Mamp trying to access and why?

Edit: I'm using the newest version of Mamp Pro 6.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In System Settings go to Privacy & Security -> Full Disc Access. Toggle the lightswitch next to Mamp Pro and restart Mamp pro.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community It's plenty clear. This was easy and worked.